# What is FEXPR and LEXPR in Maxima CAS ?

Tags: expression, maxima

What is

1. FEXPR
2. LEXPR

in Maxima CAS ?

I have found :

- [maxima-pre59 / sharem / fexpr.mc](https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/site-xml/ci/7d15abfda5d266d859983b6bef7e91e3f4bdbfad/tree/maxima-pre59/sharem/fexpr.mc)
- [tr_warn_fexpr](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_36.html)
- FEXPRs should not normally be output in translated code,

What it means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FEXPR and LEXPR were types of functions in old Lisp code (before Common Lisp). These terms apply only to obsolete Lisp systems. It's confusing that these obsolete terms are still present in the code, but you can ignore them.

Comment: Maxima version: "branch_5_38_base_389_gc891217"
Maxima build date: "2016-12-04 22:43:48"
Host type: "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
Lisp implementation type: "SBCL"
Lisp implementation version: "1.3.1.debian"